# Cannot add foreign key SQL fiddle

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm having issues with the foriegn key in my table. If any can point out the error, please do, I have no idea what it is.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_account` (
  `accountID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `typeID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`accountID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`typeID`) REFERENCES account_type(`typeID`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `account_type`(
  `typeID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `typeName` VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR (255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`typeID`),
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

As far as I'm concerned, my datatypes are fine.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do them in the opposite order after you fix the TYPO extra comma in the first table below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `account_type`(
  `typeID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `typeName` VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR (255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`typeID`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_account` (
  `accountID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `typeID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`accountID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`typeID`) REFERENCES account_type(`typeID`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: P.S. It wouldn't break my heart if you just delete the question :p

Comment: ah... hahaha. Cheers!